# Laravel Eloquent HasManyThrough relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Trying to get locations through a user.  Currently I'm getting an error, so either my hasManyThrough is setup incorrectly or my data structure is.  It's still a new project so I don't mind restructuring the database to make the default hasManyThrough work properly.

```
 $user = User::with('locations')->find(Auth::user()->id);

 echo '<pre>';
 die(print_r($user->locations,true));
```

Models:

User:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{


    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    public function locations() {
      return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Location::class,
        UserLocations::class,
      );
    }
}
```

UserLocations

```
class UserLocations extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'location_id',
  ];

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

  public function location()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
  }
}
```

Locations

```
class Location extends Model
{
  protected $fillable =
    [
      'city',
      'name',
      'timezone',
      'email',
      'state',
      'address',
      'address1',
      'zip_code',
    ];

  public function user_locations()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(UserLocations::class);
  }
}
```

Data Structure

```
Users: 
    -id
    -name
    -email
    -password

UserLocations: 
    -id
    -user_id
    -location_id

Locations: 
    -id
    -name
    -city
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have used **hasManyThrough** for this since **UserLocations** already contains the *location_id*. In your user model, use **hasManyRelationship** to **UserLocation**.

```
public function locations()
{
  return $this->hasMany(UserLocation::class, 'user_id');
}
```

And then to include the location information, just eager load it.

```
 $user = User::with(['locations.location'])->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
```